# Use angular-ui bootstrap typeahead with api callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a typeahead control to my project. I tried using the filter option, but sometimes, results are in the range of the thousands, which bring my app's performance to a crawl

So i'm going for the asynchronous method.

The problem here is, I can't use $http service to consume the api, I need to use the customer proprietary method, due to authorization reasons and it doesn't return a promise, I need to pass a success and fail callback function in order to get the results.

This is the structure of my typeahead

```
<div class="input-group typeahead">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="stopToEdit.STOP_SITE" uib-typeahead="site.SITE_CODE as site.SITE_NAME for site in sites" ng-keyup="fnGetSites(stopToEdit.STOP_SITE, stopToEdit.STOP_TYPE)"
                               typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" typeahead-popup-template-url="siteList.html" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="fnSearchSites()"><span class="fa fa-binoculars"></span></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

And this is the method I call in order to fill the sites array

```
$scope.fnGetSites = function (val, stopType) {
        if (val === '') {
            $scope.sites = null;
            return;
        } else if (val.length < 4) {
            $scope.sites = null;
            return;
        }
        $scope.showLoadingSpinner = true;
        blockUIOnCall = false;
        customerPropietaryObject.get(<api rest url to consume>, function (results) {
            $scope.sites = results;
            $scope.$digest();
        }, $scope.fnShowErroMsg);
    }
```

The problem is, results are stored correctly, but neither `$digest` nor `$apply` are working in order to show the results at the moment. I need to make another action, like, writing another character in the text box or activating the field `blur` in order to show the results.

So, if I write 'stev', I do get the results, but until I write 'steve' I get the results for 'stev'

Any idea how to solve and accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, after days of leaving this behind and focusing on something else, I finally decided to try and solve it.

The solution, in the end, was quite simple, I just needed to create my own promise as a starting point and convert my client proprietary method into a promise, and ended up with

```
var prom = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            customerPropietaryObject.get(<api rest url to consume>, function (results) { resolve(results) }, function (data) { reject(data) });
        });
        return prom.then(function (results) {            
            return results;
        });
```

Now, I just need to figure out how to show the data as a list of `KEY | VALUE` as query of the autocomplete is either for that the `key` or the `value` contains the text field text